# Python Tkinter Frames

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6, frames

Why is my program is not changing the frames like tabs?

My LoginPage checks the user and password correctly but I don't know how I can change to the main program after the validating.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import dbm

class Program(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        Frames = (LoginPage, StartPage)
        for F in Frames:
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")

        self.ShowF(LoginPage)

    def ShowF(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        stats = tk.Label(self, text = 'Insira os dados para a validação')
        stats.pack()
        lab = tk.Label(self, text = ('Usuário'))
        lab.pack()
        self.ent = tk.Entry(self)
        self.ent.pack()
        lab2 = tk.Label(self, text = ('Senha'))
        lab2.pack()
        self.ent2 = tk.Entry(self, show='*')
        self.ent2.pack()
        but = tk.Button(self, text = 'Validar', command = self.Validacao)
        but.pack()
        self.lab3 = tk.Label(self, text = '')
        self.lab3.pack()

    def Validacao(self):
        user = self.ent.get()
        passw = self.ent2.get()
        with dbm.open('files/contas','rb') as contas:
            accv = [key1.decode() for key1 in contas.keys()]
            passv = [contas[key].decode() for key in contas.keys()]
            while True:
                try:
                    k = accv.index(user)
                    k1 = passv.index(passw)
                    break
                except:
                    self.lab3['text'] = ('Usuário e/ou senha inválidos!')
                    return
            if k == k1:
                self.lab3['text'] = ('Validação concluída!')
                lambda :controller.ShowF(StartPage) #The problem is here(I think)

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Button1")
        button.pack()
        buttona = tk.Button(self, text="Button2")
        buttona.pack()

app = Program()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how your program is supposed to work?

Comment: I want to check user and password on the login screen(LoginPage), then enter in the principal program page(anotherPage) with his principal function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambda :controller.ShowF(StartPage)` does not call the function, it returns a new function that calls the function. You need to remove `lambda`:

```
self.controller.ShowF(StartPage)
```

Also, your code needs to save a reference to `controller`:

```
class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ...
```

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ThomasCaio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ThomasCaio\Documents\Python\File2.py", line 60, in Validacao
    controller.ShowF(StartPage)
NameError: name 'controller' is not defined

Comment: @ThomasCaio: yeah, that's a different problem. You need to be saving a reference to controller as `self.controller`, then make the call be `self.controller.ShowF(StartPage)`. The point being, `lambda` doesn't call the function, it simply creates a new function. That's why your code didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved creating a var:
self.var = lambda: controller.ShowF(StartPage)
then changing the button text and button['command'] = self.var